# How to scrape "data" attribute value of an img tag with Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, web-scraping, src

I'm trying to scrape data from a webpage. I wanted to get the src attribute value present inside the img tag (as marked in picture):

[image: source code]

I used the following code:

```
final picp = document.getElementsByClassName("inline-table");
pics = picp.map((e) => e.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].attributes['src']).toList();
```

Unfortunately, I got this result:

[image]

Any suggestion? thank you in advance!

Comment: these are base64 strings instead of image links, you will have to save them as image. Or if you want to show them somwhere, just put those strings in src attribute and the browser will show them as image

Comment: When you say you want to "get the src attribute value", do you mean you want to get the List of Strings, where each element would be a String with an image url?

Comment: @jabbson: Yes, that's what i want..
I want to get a List of Strings that contains every img src attribute value

Comment: See the answer to find the code that gets the list of Strings for every img.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to get a list of Strings and since you have `dart` in the tags, this gets you the list of strings with url-s. All you need to do is make a ListView out of it if your intention is to use it in the UI.

```
void main() {
  String html = getHtml(); // this gets the html with inline-tables

  Document document = parse(html);
  List<Element> tables = document.getElementsByClassName("inline-table");
  List<String?> pics = tables
      .map((e) => e.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].attributes['src'])
      .toList();

  for (var e in pics) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

I am also able to use a ListView builder to make a list out of it with

```
return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: items.length,
    itemBuilder: (contex, i) {
        return Card(child: Text(items[i] ?? ""));
    }
);
```

This code produced the result, that you can find [here](https://prnt.sc/1tyd7mh).